# Changing url path for js, css and image files with 'gulp build'

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, gulp

Since Yeoman no longer uses Grunt, I'm not sure how Gulp changes the URLs for the HTML/CSS/JS files through gulp build. I don't know what to add to the gulpfile.js to do this.

Basically, how can I have it so all my URLS change from this:

```
background-image:url('/images/example.jpg')
<img src="/images/example.jpg"/>
```

to this:

```
background-image:url('/examplefolder/examplefolder2/images/example.jpg')
<img src="/examplefolder/examplefolder2/images/example.jpg"/>
```

during the gulp-build process?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the path be relative? why do you need to hardcode your website url?

Comment: I have used this previously but not with image url though, give it a try
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-path